# Player / CameraNode Position Issue

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit, position, nodes, skcameranode

I have a camerNode position issue. I have included the code below + an attempt of resolving this with no progress. Essentially in my GameScene I have the camera locked perfectly onto the player when moving through the scene, I am actually trying to amend this so that the camera is slightly ahead of the player, this meaning my player is actually positioned on the left side of the screen, almost like an offset (+ 200) :) if this existed.

The Code:

```
        class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
        // Create a constant cam as a SKCameraNode:
        let cam = SKCameraNode()




        override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        // vertical center of the screen:
        screenCenterY = self.size.height / 2

        // Assign the camera to the scene
        self.camera = cam


        //Add the camera itself to the scene's node tree"
        self.addChild(self.camera!)
        // Position the camera node above the game elements:
        self.camera!.zPosition = 50
```

}

```
    override func didSimulatePhysics() {

        // Keep the camera locked at mid screen by default:
          var cameraYPos = screenCenterY
          cam.yScale = 1
          cam.xScale = 1

          // Follow the player:
          if (player.position.y > screenCenterY) {
          cameraYPos = player.position.y
          cam.yScale = newScale
          cam.xScale = newScale



        }

        // Camera Adjustment:
        self.camera!.position = CGPoint(x: player.position.x, y: cameraYPos)
```

I initially thought that I could overcome this by changing the player to another SKSpriteNode.. i'e in my HUD class I could add a node and apply this code around? I could then refer back to my player class in which I already defined the position above my override func didMove.

```
         let initialPlayerPosition = CGPoint(x: 50, y: 350)
```

I did try this and the GameScene started playing up, is there a better method for achieving this result? I assume the code could be changed to accommodate but I am still in the learning grounds of Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind - solved it!

Camera adjustment statement - player.position.x + 200) :)

This does the trick!